# Merge [tag:legislation] and [tag:legislative-process]

Tags: discussion, tags

We have the two tags [legislation](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legislation) and [legislative-process](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legislative-process), which have very similar excerpts and IMHO discuss the same thing:

[legislative-process](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legislative-process) (61 questions):

> Questions about the processes to create laws in different
>   jurisdictions.

[legislation](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legislation) (43 questions):

> Questions relating to the process of making or enacting laws.

I propose to merge the tags and to make [legislative-process](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legislative-process) a synonym of [legislation](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legislation).

Btw: We have [nine questions](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legislation+legislative-process) with both tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per @indigochild's comment, simply from a logical perspective, [legislation](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legislation) and [law](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/law) are better synonyms.  So one should probably be a tag alias of the other (they're both about the "sausage"), whereas [legislative-process](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legislative-process) is "how sausage is made". The current tag description of "legislation" seems rather weird to me.

Admittedly "law" is broader than "legislation", e.g. the former includes common law in the Anglo-Saxon tradition, whereas the latter is just statutory law in this context. Some might even include regulations under "law". I don't remember tagging any question with "legislation" myself, but I do think I tagged as "law" questions where I wasn't sure if something is subject to some laws and/or regulations.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative would be to differentiate them more.  E.g.

[legislative-process](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legislative-process)

> Questions about the processes to create laws in different jurisdictions.  For talking about current proposals, see [legislation](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legislation).

[legislation](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legislation)

> Questions about bills or proposals currently under consideration.  For questions about the process of enacting, see [legislative-process](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legislative-process).

Because legislation and the legislative process are certainly not the same thing.

Of course, it could be argued that we don't need a legislation tag at all.  In that case, making the two synonyms might be a temporary step before burninating the tag so as not to have to add the [legislative-process](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legislative-process) tag manually to 29 questions.  Although looking at them, most should not have the legislative-process tag on them.

I removed the [legislation](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legislation) tag from some questions, as it didn't fit there under either definition.  In some cases I added the [law](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/law) tag, as that did.

Comment: What would be the demarcation between "legislation" and "law"?

Comment: Legislation is prior to passage.  Law is after.

Comment: I would be worried that the "law" and "legislation" tags are time-dependent. Questions tagged "legislation" would need to be monitored in case their bills pass, at which point they become "law" questions.